# Create something like a Shadertoy's channel in three.js, to keep program state in a texture and read it in the "rendering" shader

Tags: three.js

I have a "logic" shader that updates the program state writing it in a texture, and a "rendering" shader that reads the state from the texture and renders the scene to the screen.

While trying to implement this, I incurred in the problem that when I read a RenderTarget's texture from a shader with texture2D(), I always get a black pixel, even if the RenderTarget has been written by a previous shader.

To try to understand the problem, I wrote the following code, where an EffectComposer fills a RenderTarget with red, and then another EffectComposer reads the RenderTarget and writes to screen:

```
var renderer;
var composer1, pass1, renderTarget1;
var composer2, pass2;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    const vertexShader = `
      void main() {
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
      }
    `

    renderTarget1 = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(64, 64)
    pass1 = new THREE.ShaderPass({
        uniforms: {},
        vertexShader,
      fragmentShader: `
        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
        }
      `
    })
    composer1 = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer, renderTarget1)
    composer1.addPass(pass1)

    pass2 = new THREE.ShaderPass({
        uniforms: {
        tRenderTarget1: { type: 't', value: renderTarget1.texture },
      },
        vertexShader,
      fragmentShader: `
        uniform sampler2D tRenderTarget1;

        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(tRenderTarget1, vec2(0.5));
        }
      `
    })
    pass2.renderToScreen = true
    composer2 = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer)
    composer2.addPass(pass2)

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}

function render() {
    composer1.render()
    composer2.render()
}
```

I expect the screen to be red, but it is black. The code can be tested here http://jsfiddle.net/matfer/f6qwr9yb/

Just to clarify, I did not put the two ShaderPasses in the same EffectComposer because they are not postprocess passes to be applied on the same image, as I said they are "logic" and "rendering" calculations that have to be written to different buffers (with different size, filtering, etc.).

What is wrong? Am I doing this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no good approach to use a render target in that way if you pass it to a `EffectComposer`. The composer internally clones the target and uses both targets to manage the read and write buffer for post processing. Since these buffers are swapped at certain points, you never know what your applied render target actually represents.

I've refactored your fiddle a bit so it has a similar style like post-processing effects with multiple passes.

http://jsfiddle.net/f6qwr9yb/7/

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean with "you never know what your applied render target actually represents"? Shouldn't EffectComposer guarantee that after its render() is called, the given RenderTarget has the final result of the passes?

Comment: I suggest you check out the source code of `EffectComposer`. It internally uses two render targets. Because of this, the given render target (the ctor parameter) represents sometimes the read, sometimes the write buffer.

Comment: I have seen the code. I guess guaranteeing that the given RenderTarget has the final result may require an additional copy pass, so for performance sake it does not work like I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is fine. You just need to define your uniforms after the constructor:

```
pass2.uniforms.tRenderTarget1.value = renderTarget1.texture;
```

Also, you can define your uniforms like this, instead.

```
uniforms: {
    tRenderTarget1: { value: null },
},
```

Specifying `type` is no longer required.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f6qwr9yb/9/

three.js r.98

Comment: Thank you! Passing the RenderTarget instead of its texture gives the warning "WebGLRenderer.setTexture2D: don't use render targets as textures. Use their .texture property instead.", however it works.